# Getting a User Account Number Saved in Class

Tags: c#

I have Created a log in form that is working correctly But what im trying to do is after the user log's in i need the account number to store somewhere so that i can save it.

This is my button Click Event Method

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string accNumMain = "";
        Menu m1 = new Menu();
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=ATM_Database.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";
        OleDbDataReader dr = null;
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string query = "Select Customer_ID,Password from Customer where Customer_ID = '" + this.userBox.Text + "' and Password = '" + this.Password.Text + "'";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_ID ", this.userBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password ", this.Password.Text);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.HasRows == true)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        accNumMain = userBox.Text;
                        Classes.AccSave AC1 = new Classes.AccSave(accNumMain);
                        MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
                        this.Hide();
                        m1.Show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    wrongEntry_Lable.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
                if (dr != null)
                {
                    dr.Close();
                }
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What i did was i saved the context into a new class which is :

```
class AccSave
{
    string acc { get; set; }

    public AccSave(string acc)
    {
        this.acc = acc;
    }
}
```

}

Im having trouble calling this class from another class to access the string var that has the AccNum in it

Comment: *Im having trouble calling this class from another class* means?

Comment: I want to call the class AccSave from anywhere and use the var so that i can use that acc to look up there account information from the data base easily

Comment: public string acc { get; set; }

Comment: where/what is String var, need more details

Comment: @terrybozzio but what would i write in the other class to use acc?

Comment: something like string somestring = AC1.acc;

Comment: @terrybozzio Okay then i would have to declare the instance again using Classes.AccSave AC1 = new Classes.AccSave(AccNum); But i have to pass throught the Accnum again that will overwrite the var

Comment: the problem is you need to access the acc variable right? 2º - you need to retrieve its value where you declare theaccsave class right?

Comment: @terrybozzio Correct AccSave has the var i would like to use in another class

Comment: then suppose that another class is named class1 and class1 as a string property lets call it strvar Classes.AccSave AC1 = new Classes.AccSave(accNumMain); then you create or you have already created the class1 object like Class1 cls = new Class1(); after that cls.strvar = AC1.acc;....thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are limiting the scope of your `AC1` to the block it was created in, why not make a Static class that you can use to store your information with out having to worry about scope.

```
class  AccSave
{
    static string _acc;
    public static string acc { get { return _acc; } set { _acc = value; } }
    public static void clear()
    {
        _acc = "";
    }

}
```

**Usuage**

```
AccSave.acc = "Your Text Here";  // Add Value
string temp = AccSave.acc;       //Retrieve Value
AccSave.Clear();                 //Clear Value
```

Comment: i told OP about storing the value of acc in another string,the thing is he wants to use acc in another class,the last 2 comments bellow his question should be all needed for clarification (apart from him wanting to create a accsave instace in that other class).

Comment: @terrybozzio That is why I suggested a static method / class, that way he doesn't have to worry about scope, it would be accessible in any class he would want/need to use it in.

Answer (score 0):

Add public to your class

```
public class AccSave{

}
```